# Generalization of Kakutani-Ky Fan Theorem without convexity assumptions

Tags: convexity, convex-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

<sub>[Crossposted](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4719368) at Mathematics SE</sub>

---

I'm wondering if there exists some extension of the Kakutani-Ky Fan Theorem

> **Theorem.**  *Let $K$ be a nonempty, compact and convex subset of a locally convex space $X$. Let $f:K\longrightarrow 2^K$ be upper semicontinuous, such that $f(x)$ is nonempty, convex and closed for every $x\in K$. Then f has a fixed point $\bar x\in K$.*

maybe without the convexity assumption of $f(x)$, or with some assumption such that $f(x)$ is homeomorphic to a convex set. I did some research in literature but, except some old articles (e.g. *I. L. Glicksberg, A Further Generalization of the Kakutani Fixed Point Theorem, with Application to Nash Equilibrium Points* and *J-P. Penot, Fixed point theorems without convexity*) which do not suit me anyway, i didn't find anything.

May you suggest me, if there are, some books or articles where I can find a similar result?

Thank you

Comment: Not a strict generalization, but the Eilenberg-Montgomery fixed point theorem might be of use.